# What dynamic model is used for the prediction step when designing a Kalman filter to compute absolute orientation from a 9dof sensor?

Tags: kalman-filter

(first: if you think this should be moved to another StackExchange where it would fit better, just let me know!).

I think that I understand relatively well the concepts behind Kalman filters, and that I "see through" the different flavors of how these ideas are applied (i.e. how Kalman filter, Extended / Linearized Kalman filter, Unscented Kalman filter, etc, "just" apply the same ideas with a few modulations on how these ideas are applied). I also think that there are a lot of very good materials online that discuss how a Kalman filter fundamentally operates and the general theory behind.

Where I struggle is to find explanations about what "good" dynamic models / sets of hypothesis are in different applications. Let me take an example, that is actually the core of this question.

I would like to understand how Kalman filters are actually deployed / implemented when used together with a 9-dof sensor (3-axis accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer), in order to produce an estimate of "absolute orientation quaternion", i.e. quaternion that describes the rotation from the sensor frame of reference, to the Earth North-East-Down frame of reference. More specifically, I have a hard time wrapping my head around what the dynamic model for the prediction step is. My problem is not with the magnetometer, so I will ignore it and focus on the 3-axis accelerometer and gyroscope and the question of "where is downwards".

I understand how the 3-axis gyroscope can be integrated in time to get orientation, and that it has high "relative accuracy", but low (even not at all) "absolute accuracy" (i..e, it drifts over time). I also understand that the 3-axis accelerometer does not "drift", and that, "in general, on average", it points downwards. So, from a high level, this means that one can use the gyro to get high accuracy orientation, and the accelerometer to know "where the downwards direction points".

However, it is not clear to me what dynamic model for the prediction state can be written to consistently describe these high level ideas. The problem I see is especially with the treatment / model around the accelerometer. "Naively" saying that:

$$
\bf{acc}_{measured} = \bf{g} + \bf{a}
$$

with $\bf{g}$ the acceleration of gravity and $\bf{a}$ the acceleration of the object itself does not provide anything useful, as this does not constrain the direction / it will always be possible to find a matching $\bf{a}$ even if the orientation of $\bf{g}$ is wrong. I see how adding a GPS that measure position and velocity would alleviate the problem - since the value of $\bf{a}$ would get "constrained" by the GPS data, so that the acc equation would actually constrain $\bf{g}$ and provide some information about what the vertical is. But in a case with only a 9-dof sensor, I suppose that there must be some additional "tricks / hypothesis" going in the dynamic model, likely somehow expressing into the dynamic model for the prediction step that "in average, acceleration points down".

My question is: how can / is such a "good" dynamic model formulated in this case? I cannot find resources online about this specific example, but I may be missing something / some resources.

Answer (score 1):

The Kalman Filter (KF) and variants are separated in predict and update steps where the predict steps incorporate the dynamics of the system and the update steps incorporate the measurements.

Often, the accelerometers and gyroscopes are used to model the control inputs (i.e., dynamics). For example, consider an ground vehicle navigating using an inertial measurement unit (IMU) and Global Positioning System (GPS). The IMU is used for the predict step (i.e., integrating to obtain velocity and position), and the GPS is used for the update step (i.e., correcting the position).

In contrast, the dynamics may be modeled in other ways. For example, the applied acceleration (e.g., gas/brakes) and applied rotation rate (e.g., steering angle) may be used for predicting the velocity and position. However, these quantities may be estimated using sensors (e.g., accelerometers and gyroscopes) or estimated based on the control inputs (e.g., if gas/brakes are applied, a certain acceleration is assumed).

Lastly, accelerometers drift much more than gyroscopes in the sense that to get position double integration is required while to get orientation single integration is required. However, for estimating tilt, accelerometers do not drift (ignoring biases).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of the predict and update steps. My question is rather about how accelerometers are usually "integrated" into the Kalman filter to estimate tilt / the vertical direction, when writing an attitude Kalman filter. I guess there is some form of time averaging of some kind to get the vertical direction, that is used as a measure. Any details about how this is implemented in details, which equations / hypothesis are usually used?

Comment: @Zorglub29 Typically, tilt is integrated in a simple KF as measurements e.g., if you are using euler angles (in your state vector), you can calculate the roll, pitch, and yaw via the accelerometers, then you use those values for roll, pitch, and yaw in your update step. No need for averaging.

Comment: Any reference / example of implementation/ list of tips and tricks you know about? :)